# Can't send https get request to SOAP by ip python

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, pem

This might be a security question more than python, but here we go.

I want to get data from a web service with this url: https://x.x.x.x/serviceWS/server.php?wsdl. They have sent me the Key, CRT and PEM file, but I can't make it work: So far I have this code:

```
import requests
crt = '/path/to/crt'
key = '/path/to/key'
pem = '/path/to/pem'
body = '<soap>...</soap>'

res = requests.get(ws, cert=(crt, key), verify=pem)
```

and it gives me this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 332, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /serviceWS/server.php?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /serviceWS/server.php?wsdl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

My guess is because the certificates are for a domain like: '*.remotework.com.pe', while i'm trying to connect to an ip. If this is the problem, the code will never work until they put the right domain, right?

Any help will be nice!

Comment: Just to be sure the cert is indeed valid (and this is not caused by you getting a wrong cert), have you tried testing the service using something like SoapUI? This kind of software can easily take away the uncertainty factor of your code whilst testing the service.

Comment: "while i'm trying to connect to an ip." You always connect to an IP at the end  but you need indeed to pass a name to the library connecting for you, because indeed any decent library HAS TO compare the hostname given with what is in the certificate (otherwise the server certificate is kind of pointless).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that was the key to find the solution. I had to add the destination ip to the /etc/host file and everything worked fine! Thank you!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and then validate it so that your question will be closed and people could benefit from your findings in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got the solution following the comments:

As Patrick said: "You always connect to an IP at the end but you need indeed to pass a name to the library connecting for you, because indeed any decent library HAS TO compare the hostname given with what is in the certificate". The destination host was unknown. I modified the **/etc/hosts** file, writing the ip and the name of the certificate and it worked.

Many thanks!!